# Automatically update hyperlink to point to newest added document in a library

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, promoted-links

This is my first post here, so bear with me.
I am reletivley new to SharePoint, however I do know my way around it.

Basically on my site homepage I have promoted links set up along the top. One of these links is a 'weekly news bulletin'. Obviously as this will be updated weekly i was wonderinig if there was a way I could automatically update the hyperlink on the promoted link to point to the newest added document in a library elsewhere in the site. (The document will be added within a folder in a library within this same site).

I would imagine there is some way to do this however any guidance would be great.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Take a look at the Content Query Web Part

Comment: I know it is doable using JavaScript, but I currently can't offer a good workaround :(

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve it is using SharePoint Designer Workflow,

1. Say you have a Document library with name 'Test Documents' and Promoted links list as 'Latest Document Link'
2. Create a **SharePoint Designer Workflow** for the 'Test Documents' Library
3. Set the **'Start Option of the Workflow'** as **'Start Workflow when an item is created'**
4. In the Workflow, `Update item in Latest Document Link`, set the filter condition and update values as per the requirement.

Note: I dont think this will be possible by JavaScript/JQuery, as there is no option to call a JavaScript after creation of item. Either we have to call the JavaScript in PreSaveAction() in NewForm/EditForm of library, but that too you may not get the newly uploaded document URL as the PreSaveAction will be triggered before upload of the document. So go with SPD Workflow.